# Automatically append span to external links - target _blank

Tags: jquery, wordpress, hyperlink

I would like to automatically append a span to any link that has a target "_blank".  The purpose of this is for screen readers to read "(opens in a new tab)" but to visually be hidden with the "screen-reader-text" span.

**Example link:**

`<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>`

**Example link after appended span:**

`<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Google<span class="screen-reader-text"> (opens in new tab)</a>`

So all the user would have to do (in WordPress) is create a link that opens in a new tab/window and the appended span would automatically be added to the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(“a[target=‘_blank’]”).append(‘<span class="screen-reader-text"> (opens in new tab) <\span>’);
```

That should do it

Comment: Closing span can be corrected </span>

Answer (score 0):

Although you could dynamically insert the `<span></span>` tag using JavaScript, many screen readers may not execute the JavaScript code, so the audience will never hear the annotation. To make your site accessible, include the span in all versions of the site, and hide it from visual visitors using CSS.

The Twitter Bootstrap framework uses the following CSS rules for their `sr-only` class:

```
.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
  border: 0;
}
```

Notice that this class doesn't contain any `display: none;` or `width: 0px; height: 0px;` rules that may cause certain screen readers to ignore the content.

To answer your question directly, here's an example with jQuery:

```
$("a[target='_blank']").append('<span class="screen-reader-text">...</span>');
```